# find matches for positive and negative number in arithmetic expression

Tags: regex

Given the following arithmetic expression:
-1-5+(-3+2)

There is need to find matches for positive and negative numbers. For that expression expected result is: -1 5 -3 2

I tried to use regex -?\d+(.\d+)? but it returns: -1 -5 -3 2 where -5 is not correct.

Is that possible to build regex pattern to get positive and negative numbers for that case and other similar cases ?

Comment: What language/tool are you using? If supported, lookbehinds might lead to a [solution](https://regex101.com/r/bR5kD9/1).

Comment: You have to define (to yourself and to regex) why -1 is correct but -5 is not correct.

Comment: You can use `(^|\D)([-]?\d*\.?\d+)` (in JS), or `(?<!\d)[-]?\d*\.?\d+` (if it is a better regex engine).

Comment: (?<!\d)[-]?\d*\.?\d+  from  Wiktor Stribiżew
and 
((?<!\d)-)?\d+(?:\.\d+)? from  Sebastian Proske

Exactly what I needed
Thanks for quick response

Comment: @Alex, I posted my suggestion and added explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!\d)[-]?\d*\.?\d+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vI0tS1/1)

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<!\d)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if a digit appears before the currently tested position
- `[-]?` - an optional (1 or 0) minus sign
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `\.?` - 1 or 0 dots (a literal dot as it is escaped)
- `\d+` - 1+ digits

Note that `\d*\.?\d+` allows `.456` values, if you do not need that, just use `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`.

If the lookbehind is not supported, use a capturing group with alternation to check if the `-` is not at the start of the string or before another digit:

```
(?:^|\D)([-]?\d*\.?\d+)
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/zI5xU6/1) (the necessary value is in Group 1).

Answer (score 0):

`/((?:^|\+|-|\()(-?\d+))/`

You don't say what language/script you're using, but here's a PHP example:

```
$string = '-1-5+(-3+2)';
preg_match_all('/(?:^|\+|-)(-?\d+)/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => -1
    [1] => 5
    [2] => -3
    [3] => 2
)
```

[PHP Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7c4f9430073b173895d9024a4dc42209f6a80e5a)

EXPLANATION: There's two grouped patterns:

```
/
  (?:^|\+|-|\()
  (-?\d+)
/
```

The first group is a non-capturing group `?:`, and an alternation, that is, match any character in the list. There's 4 characters in that list:

`^` line start

`\+` literal plus

`-` minus

`\(` literal open paren

The first group is there to make the optional `-` in the second group stand out. Every digit (positive or negative) will be preceded by one of the characters listed in the first group, now match all that follows including the `-` if present.